# Scala Spark: How to pad a sublist inside a dataframe with extra values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe, `originalDF`, which looks like this

```
+--------+--------------+
|data_id |data_list     |
+--------+--------------+
|       3| [a, b, d]    |
|       2|[c, a, b, e]  |
|       1|         [g]  |
+--------+--------------+
```

And I have another dataframe, `extraInfoDF`, which looks like this:

```
+--------+--------------+
|data_id |data_list     |
+--------+--------------+
|       3| [q, w, x, a] |
|       2|[r, q, l, p]  |
|       1| [z, k, j, f] |
+--------+--------------+
```

For the two `data_lists` in `originalDF` that are shorter than 4, I want to add in data from the corresponding `data_lists` in `extraInfoDF` so that each list has a length of 4.

The resulting dataframe would look like:

```
+--------+--------------+
|data_id |data_list     |
+--------+--------------+
|       3| [a, b, d, q] |
|       2|[c, a, b, e]  |
|       1|[g, z, k, j]  |
+--------+--------------+
```

I was trying to find some way to iterate through each row in the dataframe and append to the list that way but was having trouble. Now I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to accomplish this with a UDF?

Comment: You can first merge them, then resize it.

Comment: If I merge them, will the order remain the same? So [c, a, b, e] would still be the first 4 for data_id 2 when I resize it down to 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the second list to the first and `take` the left-most N elements in a UDF, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

def padList(n: Int) = udf{ (l1: Seq[String], l2: Seq[String]) =>
  (l1 ++ l2).take(n)
}

val df1 = Seq(
  (3, Seq("a", "b", "d")),
  (2, Seq("c", "a", "b", "e")),
  (1, Seq("g"))
).toDF("data_id", "data_list")

val df2 = Seq(
  (3, Seq("q", "w", "x", "a")),
  (2, Seq("r", "q", "l", "p")),
  (1, Seq("z", "k", "j", "f"))
).toDF("data_id", "data_list")

df1.
  join(df2, "data_id").
  select($"data_id", padList(4)(df1("data_list"), df2("data_list")).as("data_list")).
  show
// +-------+------------+
// |data_id|   data_list|
// +-------+------------+
// |      3|[a, b, d, q]|
// |      2|[c, a, b, e]|
// |      1|[g, z, k, j]|
// +-------+------------+
```